# Excluding names and values

Tags: excel, vba

I Have two columns in my Worksheet. One holding names, the other holding values. Two persons in the Name column has values=0. I want to exclude both the names and values for these two persons. What is the VBA code?

Comment: Do you want to **delete** the entries or **hide** the entries *(by filtering)* ???

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Sub Init()
    Range("A1").Value = "Names"
    Range("A2").Value = "Petter"
    Range("A3").Value = "Peter"
    Range("A4").Value = "Peter2"
    Range("A5").Value = "Petter3"
    Range("A6").Value = "Petter4"

    Range("B1").Value = "Values"
    Range("B2").Value = 1
    Range("B3").Value = 2
    Range("B4").Value = 0
    Range("B5").Value = 3
    Range("B6").Value = 0
End Sub

Sub Delete_Values_If_0()
Dim lastRow As Long
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=0
    lastRow = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    Debug.Print lastRow
    Range("2:" & lastRow).Delete
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter
End Sub

Sub Hide_Values_If_0()
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>0", Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub

Sub FilterOff()
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
         ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That's great! Please accept my answer. **To accept an answer:** (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)